# JTextArea Output

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Good Evening, What can I do to have the output from jTExtArea like in the console?
You can see the image how it is, I use .append to show the output in jTextArea [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLPEp.jpg)

Code:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < a.pattern_cnt; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < a.T_element_cnt; j++) {
                 System.out.printf("%.3f\t", a.O[i][j]); //console output

                 t1.append(a.O[i][j]+" ");//jtextarea output
                }

                System.out.println();


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the font to monospaced.

```
t1.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Edit:

And add new line in main iteration and use string format.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < a.pattern_cnt; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.T_element_cnt; j++) {
             System.out.printf("%.3f\t", a.O[i][j]); //console output

             t1.append(String.format("%.3f\t", a.O[i][j]));//jtextarea output
            }

            System.out.println();
            t1.append("\n");

        }
```

Comment: actually not :(

Comment: What's the result?

Comment: the same, only shrift changed

Comment: And use `String.format("%.3f\t", a.O[i][j])` for the `JTextArea` call, as it is done in `System.out.printf(...)`.

Comment: Izruo -how can I do that?

Comment: @JohnCoffey Put it in the `JTextArea.append(...)` method instead of what is currently there. After all `System.out.printf(...)` is just a shortcut for `System.out.print(String.format(...))`, too.

Comment: @Izruo , almost...now, do you know how can i group to be like 3 result in one line? like in the console?
https://ibb.co/jqBMuw

Comment: @JohnCoffey Use the `t1.append("\n")` fix, Thomas already provided. It will add a newline after all `a.T_element_cnt` outputs which I suppose is always equal to `3`.